# Lubuntu 18.04 freezes after hours of idling

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04

I have a Lubuntu 18.04 installation on a flash drive that consistently freezes after being left for an amount of time, about the span of a day.

I don't know what logs to pull, could you comment and tell me which?

Edit: The shortest recorded timespan so far is around 4 hours... I closed the lid and left the laptop to run ddrescue on a 120GB SSD and a file transfer, and when I come back and the mouse works, but I can't click or type into the login prompt.

Edit: After coming back to the system, I've noticed that every time it freezes, previously used functions like the browser will continue to work for a few seconds before totally locking up. In addition, all sysrq keys are enabled and using `Ctrl + Sysrq + R` I can easily navigate all `tty`s. However, all the `tty`s do not respond to input, but do display tty number and prompt.

Edit: A few minutes after looking at `tty1`, a message appeared.
    [31207.163210] systemd[1]: Failed to start Journal Service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this happens in Ubuntu/Lubuntu in case you are using Laptop I don't know why. But the solution is choose the option 'do nothing' or make it clear that It do not 'suspend'. Hope this solves the problem.